# How Do You Center Float?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have three `h3` tags within a `div` tag. I'm trying to place all three `h3` tags on the same horizontal line, with the first `h3` tag being left aligned, the second `h3` tag being centered, and the third `h3` tag being right aligned. I have looked for an answer on here and found many, but have not been able to implement them correctly. Thanks

Here is the HTML5 code

```
<div class="education">                         
    <h3 class="date"> April 2013 – Present</h3> 
    <h3 class="place"> Sutton ON, Canada </h3> 
    <h3 class="company" > All Reasons Party Rentals </h3>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS3

```
h3.date {
    text-align:left; 
    display:inline-block; 
    float:left;
}   
h3.company {
    text-align:center; 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}   
h3.place {
    text-align:right; 
    display:inline-block; 
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand that answer in relation to mine, I'm quite a novice. Although it might answer my question, I cant seem to use it to fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you had the `h3.company` and `h3.place` selectors the wrong way round with their properties, so the layout was fighting with the order of the HTML.

But, I think this will work:

```
.education h3 {float:left;padding:0;margin:0;width:33.333%;}

h3.date {text-align:left;}
h3.place {text-align:center;}
h3.company {text-align:right;}
```

Working here, with coloured backgrounds on the headings so you can see exactly what the widths are:
http://jsfiddle.net/QfAeA/

A run down of how this works:

- All 3 headings are floated and given the same width, a third of the available space, so they share it equally
- The padding and margin has been set to 0 so it doesn't make them wider than 33.333% and ruin the layout
- Then you only have to deal with the text alignment for each heading

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your's is the best answer and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `text-align:center` on the container, `body` in this case, and float the two on the outside. This allows for any (or varying) width of any of the elements while remaining perfectly aligned. On small screens it turns into a vertical layout to fit

```
body { text-align:center; }
h3.date {
    text-align:left; 
    float:left;
}   
h3.company {
    margin:20px auto;
    display:inline-block;
}   
h3.place {
    text-align:right; 
    float:right;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/7sqkB/)

If you want the company name to remain on top of the others on small screens, position it ahead of the floats in the HTML

Answer (score -1):

Please see the code

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="tabletContainer">


        <div class="left">
            <h3>April 2013 – Present</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <h3>All Reasons Party Rentals</h3> 
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Sutton ON, Canada </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

**CSS**

```
   /* reset browser styles */
    html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        line-height: 1.2;
    }

    ol {
        padding-left: 1.4em;
        list-style: decimal;
    }

    ul {
        padding-left: 1.4em;
        list-style: square;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    /* end reset browser styles */

    /*Fill all available spaces*/

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

    }


    .container {
        width: auto;
    }

        .container:after {
            content: " ";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }


    .tabletContainer {
        /*The total width for the first two column*/
        width: 67%;
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }



    .left {

        float: left;
        /*Each column takes have of the container size, so their width =67/2 = 33.5%*/
        width: 50%;
    }

    .middle {

        float: right;
        /*Each column takes have of the container size, so their width =67/2 = 33.5%*/
        width: 50%;
    }

    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 33%;

    }

    .right h3 {
        float: right;
    }

    /*For tablet devices, show only the two columns in a row and a column underneath*/

    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
        .tabletContainer, .right {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
        }

      .right
      {
          clear: both;
          width: 50%;


      }

        .right h3 {
            float: left;
        }
    }


    /*For mobile phones, show only one column*/
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
       .tabletContainer, .left, .right, .middle {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
           display: block;
        }
        .right h3 {
            float: left;
        }



    }
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KxryX/

EDIT: OK as Jason and Zach suggested that the original solution was not responsive. I have updated to make it responsive.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea to do for several reasons

Comment: When viewed on a device or browser window with width less than 554px this proposed solution starts to break down.

Comment: @JasonAller I agree, but the question is how to arrange the components, not about responsive design. I would change to a responsive design if it required. Cheers.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @ToanNguyen 1. They are not responsive 2. They break other things like stacking order 3. Without using `calc` or negative margins their positioning is based on their dimensions, not allowing for them to be resized and retain perfect positioning 4. Hard to manage and add to (such as adding a fourth element)

Comment: I managed to do it using a <table> Thanks for all your help!!!